# Redshift - Applying regex based on certain rules

Tags: sql, regex, amazon-redshift

I am trying to apply a filter based on values in 2 columns in a Redshift table as shown below:

```
column_1, column_2
PROD_Label1, TYPE1_PROD_lbll1_Category_XYZ
PROD_Label1, TYPE2_PROD_lbll2_Category_XYZ
```

`column_1` has the word **Label** fully entered whereas `column_2` has it abbreviated to **lbl** with some additional text.

I am trying to see how could I filter to get only the first row from the above dataset.

The way I am trying to map is to check `Label1` in the first column with `lbl1` in the second column

Expected output:

```
column_1, column_2
PROD_Label1, TYPE1_PROD_lbll1_Category_XYZ
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The way I am trying to map is to check Label1 in the first column with lbl1 in the second column

This doesn't sound like a regular expression.  It sounds like a `where` clause:

```
select t.*
from t
where column_1 like '%Label1' and column2 like '%lbll1%'
```